# implement stack with freelist feature in Python 2.7

Tags: python, python-2.7, stack

Design a stack with free list feature (i.e. after a node is popped, its space is reusable by future push operation, and kept in free list). The code is simplified and does not make sense in some perspective, and I just use below code to show the general idea of stack with free list (as a prototype).

My question is about how to design `pop` operation. My confusion is since a reference to a node is returned after `pop` operation, for example in my code there is `node1 = stack.pop()`, the reference to a node might be used by client who call `pop`, and the same node reference is reclaimed in free list and might be used by other `push` operation, how to resolve such conflict and wondering for general advice for design free list feature with stack, linked list or queue.

```
MAXSIZE = 100
freeListHead = None

class StackNode:
    def __init__(self, value, nextNode):
        self.value = value
        self.nextNode = nextNode
class Stack:
    def __init__(self):
        self.top = None
        self.size = 0
    def peek(self):
        # return StackNode
        return self.top
    def push(self, value):
        global freeListHead
        if self.size >= MAXSIZE:
            raise Exception('stack full')
        node = freeListHead
        node.value = value
        freeListHead = node.nextNode
        node.nextNode = self.top
        self.top = node
        self.size += 1
    def pop(self):
        if self.size == 0:
            return None
        node = self.top
        self.top = self.top.nextNode
        self.size -= 1
        return node

if __name__ == "__main__":
    # initialization for nodes and link them to be a free list
    nodes = [StackNode(-1, None) for i in range(MAXSIZE)]
    freeListHead = nodes[0]
    for i in range(0, len(nodes)-1):
        nodes[i].nextNode = nodes[i+1]
    stack = Stack()
    stack.push(1)
    stack.push(50)
    stack.push(100)
    stack.push(200)
    print stack.peek().value
    node1 = stack.pop()
    print node1.value
    print stack.peek().value
```

Comment: Why would you return a node from `pop` when your `push` accepts values, not nodes? For me it would make more sense for `pop` to return exactly same thing that was given to `push`.

Comment: @niemmi, nice catch. This is one good option. Is there solution if I want both `push` and `pop` deal with `StackNode` other than `int`?

Comment: It already does, see your `push` implementation, it takes a parameter but doesn't care about the type. In the same way you can have `pop` to return `node.value` no matter the type.

Comment: Thanks @niemmi, I mean if I need to return `StackNode` from `pop` (for the purpose of encapsulation, since `StackNode` can wrap a lot of other stuff other than just an `int`), any advice how to avoid conflict?

Comment: Think it this way: What are you going to do with the returned `node` on top of accessing property like `node.value`?

Comment: @niemmi, client of `pop` may use change `value` (suppose it is not `int` in real, it is a complex type), and free list also need to use `value` to reuse memory purpose. Any ideas how to resolve the conflict?

Comment: @niemmi, not sure if there is a neat way to clone `StackNode` and pop returns a cloned instance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could simplify your code by returning the `value` given to `push` instead of `StackNode` holding the value. There are no concerns of memory consumption since you can set `node.value` to `None` in `pop` before returning the result. Below is simple example on how this would work in the practice:

```
class Node:
    def __init__(self):
        self.nextNode = self.value = None

class Stack:
    def __init__(self, maxSize):
        self.maxSize = maxSize
        self.size = 0
        self.top = self.free = None

    def push(self, value):
        if self.size == self.maxSize:
            raise Exception('Stack full')

        if self.free:
            node = self.free
            self.free = node.next
        else:
            node = Node()

        node.value = value
        node.nextNode = self.top
        self.top = node
        self.size += 1

    def pop(self):
        if not self.top:
            raise Exception('Stack empty');
        node = self.top
        self.top = node.nextNode
        node.nextNode = self.free
        self.free = node
        self.size -= 1
        result = node.value
        node.value = None

        return result

stack = Stack(3)
for i in range(3):
    stack.push(list(range(i + 1)))

while stack.size:
    print(stack.pop())
```

Output:

```
[0, 1, 2]
[0, 1]
[0]
```

Comment: Thanks, and vote up, but I have concern if you `node.value = None`, then free list has no purpose since the memory space used by the popped node cannot be reused.

Comment: @LinMa I'm not sure I follow you here since popped nodes are being reused in `push` method. Let's assume the stack would store the values returned from `pop`. Then next time when `push` is called how could the stack know if the client has stored the returned `value` somewhere and is going to use it later or if it's somehow available for reuse by stack?

Comment: Thanks, and vote up for the reply, actually my purpose of using free list is to save time/memory of creating new `StackNode` object and re-use the memory consumed by `value`, your code could achieve the objective (especially the latter one)?

Comment: Another thought is, whether or not assign `result = node.value` does not matter, since `node.value` is just a reference. When you `push`, `node.value` will be pointed to the new value, so no impact to existing value already popped to client, correct?

Comment: @LinMa It matters because Python uses [garbage collection](http://arctrix.com/nas/python/gc/) and GC can't collect the object as long as it's being referred to. So setting the `node.value` to `None` in `pop` allows GC to free the object as soon as caller is done with it.

Comment: Thanks, but if using classic CPython, still have GC involved?

Comment: @LinMa: Yes, CPython has garbage collection. You can find the interface from https://docs.python.org/2/library/gc.html.

Comment: Thanks niemmi, nice reference, mark your reply as answer.